# Is this temperature normal with this hardware?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel, fan, temperature

Is the data received from XSensor normal? I'm using an NVIdia

[image: Temperature screenshot]

Here are the details of my laptop:

[image: Laptop details]

Comment: If you google "normal temperature for computer" you get a bunch of good results, like this article: [Optimal CPU and GPU Temperatures For Gaming - GamingScan](https://www.gamingscan.com/optimal-cpu-and-gpu-temperatures-for-gaming/)